# If statement gives wrong result

Tags: c, if-statement, int, printf, logical-or

I am trying to write a program which takes user input for an area code and based on that it displays the corresponding Area which the area code is for based on this table:

Area code -----------   Major City

229       ---------------------    Albany

404      ---------------------     Atlanta

470       ---------------------   Atlanta

478        ---------------------   Macon

678     ---------------------      Atlanta

706       ---------------------    Columbus

762       ---------------------    Columbus

770      ---------------------     Atlanta

912       ---------------------    Savannah

***This is my code below the problem i have is that the IF statement gives me incorrect results such as for example if i input 912 it will give me "Atlanta" which is incorrect since in the IF statement it says if 912 is equal to user input "Savannah" should display.***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main(){

int AreaNum;

printf("enter a area code: ");
scanf("%d", &AreaNum);

if (AreaNum == 229){
printf("Albany");
}else if (AreaNum == 404 || 470 || 678 || 770){
printf("Atlanta");
}else if (AreaNum == 478){
printf("Macon");
}else if (AreaNum == 706 || 762){
printf("Columbus");
}else if (AreaNum == 912){
printf("Savannah");
}else
printf("Area code not recognized");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `A == B || C` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @Beta please explain what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such an if statement like this

```
}else if (AreaNum == 404 || 470 || 678 || 770){
```

is equivalent to the following

```
}else if ( ( AreaNum == 404 ) || ( 470 )|| ( 678 ) || ( 770 ) ){
```

So if for example the first sub-expression `AreaNum == 404` evaluates to false then the second and subsequent expressions like  `( 470 )` are not equal to zero so they evaluate to true and the whole expression yields the value true.

From the C Standard (6.5.14 Logical OR operator)

> 3 The || operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare
>   unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.

And neither 470, nor 678 or 770 in the above expression are equal to 0. So the condition in this if statement will always yield true independent on whether AreaNum is equal to 404 or not.

That is the above if statement may be equivalently rewritten the following way

```
}else if ( ( AreaNum == 404 ) || ( 470 != 0 )|| ( 678 != 0 ) || ( 770 != 0 ) ){
```

It seems you mean the following

```
}else if ( ( AreaNum == 404 ) || ( AreaNum == 470 )|| ( AreaNum == 678 ) || ( AreaNum == 770 ) ){
```

Comment: Nice explanation but can you please explain that again in a less technical language, im new to programming and find that explanation hard to grasp

Comment: @Qasim in C any expression that is not equal to 0 is evaluated to true. For example if( 1 ) {} evaluates to true. So if you will write if ( 2 == 5 || 10 ) {} that is equivalent to if ( ( 2 == 5 ) || ( 10 ) ) {} then as 10 is not equal to 0 then the whole expression evaluates to true even though 2 is not equal to 5.

Comment: wait but 2 is not directly equal to 5 so does that mean the whole expression evaluates too false ?

Comment: @Qasim For the logical OR operator it is enough that one of its operands (in the example above either ( 2 == 5 ) or ( 10 ) ) would evaluate to true. As 10 is not equal to 0 then this operand evaluates to true. You can consider the second operand like ( 10 != 9 )

Comment: could i think of it like this so firstly 2 is not directly equal to 5 which is a value of 0, but then when 10 is checked it is by itself and by default has a value of 1, and 1 is more dominant that 0 so the whole expression is evaluated as 1.

Comment: @Qasim As it is wrote in the quote from the C standard if an expression evaluates to unequal to 0 then the condition yields true. The expression 2 == 5 yields 0. The expression 2 == 2 yields 1. So 2 == 5 yields 0 but 10 != 0 yields 1. So the whole expression yields 1. It is logical OR operator. It is not the logical AND operator when the both operands shall yield 1  to provide that the whole expression would be true.

Comment: ohhhhhh i understand now, but one last question what is the default boolean value of a variable in any random expression? for example in my question 404 is 0, but 470 etc. are 1 why is this and what is the default value of a number like this, is it 1 or 0

Comment: @Qasim 404 is not  0. It is 404 that is unequal to 0. SO if this is statement if ( 404 ) {} is equivalent to if ( 404 != 0 ) {}. In the example from the answer there is used the expression AreaNum == 404 that either evaluates to 1 if AreaNum is equal to  404 or to 0 otherwise.

Comment: I think i understand now thank you so much for helping me understand this any resources you would recommend for me to get as good as you in C :P.

Comment: @Qasim I advice to visit this site more often and try to answer questions of others.

Answer (score 0):

`AreaNum == 404 || 470 || 678 || 770` doesn't do what you want, and will in fact always evaluate to true. This is because by order of operations, it's effectively `(AreaNum == 404) || 470 || 678 || 770`, so after checking against the first one, there will just be a number with no check, and in C, nonzero numbers are truthy. You have two choices. Either write them all out in long form, like `AreaNum == 404 || AreaNum == 470 || AreaNum == 678 || AreaNum == 770`, or use a `switch` statement instead of your `if` statements, like this:

```
switch(AreaNum) {
case 229:
    printf("Albany");
    break;
case 404:
case 470:
case 678:
case 770:
    printf("Atlanta");
    break;
case 478:
    printf("Macon");
    break;
case 706:
case 762:
    printf("Columbus");
    break;
case 912:
    printf("Savannah");
    break;
default:
    printf("Area code not recognized");
}
```

Comment: please elaborate on the answer and tell me what it does

Comment: @Qasim What part in particular don't you understand?

Comment: "You said AreaNum == 404 || 470 || 678 || 770 doesnt do what you want" why doesnt it and why does it evaluate to true